# Can't find installation configuration file

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-install

I aim to use the 'drama' python package [[link]](https://sdup.esoc.esa.int/drama/python_package_docs/installation.html).

I installed 'drama' using `PIP` (when tried to instal using `PIP3` I get an error that `pip3` is not defined). I am running Python 3.7 in Spyder.

The package confirms it is installed but a kernel restart may be required. I restarted the kernel.

When I run the example showed in [link](https://sdup.esoc.esa.int/drama/python_package_docs/known_issues.html):

```
from drama import oscar 
results = oscar.run(sma=[6500, 6550],parallel=False)
```

I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: Can't find DRAMA installation configuration file. A
> reinstallation of DRAMA 3.0.4 should fix it.

I double checked and drama is listed when I check `pip list`.

Any ideas on what I could try to solve this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: If your PIP command is associated with python2, and you're running python3, it won't find it. Try installing with pip3 again - just installed on my linux machine and it's worked fine.

Comment: Thank you @Luke. I am struggling to instal pip3. Strangely I have python 3.7 but  pip3 seems to be unavailable. Once I use pip3 I will report if it solved the issue. (first time installing an outside package) Thanks

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am on macOS 11.4.